# what's the code meaning? UITextFieldDelegate

Tags: ios, delegates, uitextfield, textfield, uitextfielddelegate

How does this code work -

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField.resignFirstResponder() {
        textField.text = nil
    }
    return true
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    theTextField.text = textField.text
}
```

I don't understand it, I know what it does but i need some help to understand what the codes mean. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

`ShouldReturn` have to be called earlier than `DidEndEditing,` if  `ShouldReturn`
ends with true. `TextField` is a first responder, therefore `textField.text` and `theTextField.text` are nil.

I could assume that original idea is to copy value from `textField` to `theTextField`, and nullify the first field.
`ShouldReturn` is called to figure out if editing is finished, and resign method will deactivate currently active `textField`.

Then after that `DidEndEditing(_ textField` is going to be called for the first(resigned) textField, but the text is already nil(was reset), that is thy `theTextField.text` is going to be nil.

Please check the [UITextFieldDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldDidEndEditing%3A)

Comment: Thanks for the help!